# Reducing if statements in python

Tags: python

I'm making a program which iterates over a list and it is a huge list of if statements right now:

```
def next_button():
    print('Finding next button...')
    continue_blue = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
        'continueblue.jpg', confidence=0.9)
    continue_red = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
        'continuered.jpg', confidence=0.9)
    next_button4 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
        'continue4.jpg', confidence=0.9)
    next_button5 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
        'continue5.jpg', confidence=0.9)
    next_button6 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
        'continue6.jpg', confidence=0.9)
    next_button7 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
        'continue7.jpg', confidence=0.9)
    next_button9 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
        'continue9.jpg', confidence=0.9)
    if continue_blue:
        pause()
        pyautogui.click(continue_blue)
    if continue_red:
        pause()
        pyautogui.click(continue_red)
    if next_button4:
        pause()
        pyautogui.click(next_button4)
    if next_button5:
        pause()
        pyautogui.click(next_button5)
    if next_button6:
        pause()
        pyautogui.click(next_button6)
    if next_button7:
        pause()
        pyautogui.click(next_button7)
    if next_button9:
        pause()
        pyautogui.click(next_button9)
    print('Next clicked')
```

Obviously, this is really unsightly and goes against DRY code.  How do I reduce the number of if statements in a function?  Any other suggestions on how I can improve this? Thank you!

Comment: using `dict` might help at some extent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all button images and click if found. Note that it will click multiple buttons, if multiples are found, just like in your script.

```py
def next_button():
    print('Finding next button...')
    button_images = [
        'continueblue.jpg',
        'continuered.jpg',
        'continue4.jpg',
        'continue5.jpg',
        'continue6.jpg',
        'continue7.jpg',
        'continue9.jpg'
    ]
    for button_image in button_images:
        button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(button_image, confidence=0.9)
        if button:
            pause()
            pyautogui.click(button)
    print('Next clicked')
```

Comment: Hello and thank you! I was looking for a loop and have used some of your idea in order to make the program better!

Comment: @TheWongandOnly Then could you please accept it? Cheers!

Comment: Done.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it into a loop

```
buttons = ['continueblue.jpg', 'continuered.jpg', ...]
def next_button():
    for button_img in buttons:
        button_obj = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
            button_img, confidence=0.9)
        if button_obj:
            pause()
            pyautogui.click(button_obj)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you! This was essentially what I was looking for.  Loop is a perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the buttons as separate variables, arrange them into a list:

```
buttons = [
    pyautogui.locateOnScreen('continueblue.jpg', confidence=0.9),
    pyautogui.locateOnScreen('continuered.jpg', confidence=0.9),
    ...
]
```

Then you can iterate over them:

```
for button in buttons:
    if button:
        pause()
        pyautogui.click(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the order matters, but you could try this solution:

```
def next_button():
    print('Finding next button...')
    images = ['continueblue.jpg','continuered.jpg', 'continue4.jpg', 'continue5.jpg','continue6.jpg', 'continue7.jpg', 'continue9.jpg'
    for im in images:
       continue_var = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(im, confidence=0.9)
       if continue_var:
           pause()
           pyautogui.click(continue_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial functions to avoid duplication at many places. Finally put all the actions in dictionary and call that dictionary with its key and function call parenthesis.
Below is a pseudo code for you.

```
from functools import partial

def next_button(jpg, conf):
    next_b = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(jpg, confidence=conf)
    pause()
    pyautogui.click(next_b)

action = {
    continue_blue : partial(next_button, 'continueblue.jpg', 0.9)
    continue_red : partial(next_button, 'continuered.jpg', 0.9)
    next_button4 : partial(next_button, 'continue4.jpg', 0.9)
    next_button5 : partial(next_button, 'continue5.jpg', 0.9)
    ------
    ------
}

action['continue_red']()
```

Answer (score -2):

import pyautogui

arr['continueblue.jpg','continuered.jpg','continue4.jpg','continue5.jpg','continue6.jpg','continue7.jpg','continue9.jpg']

for i in arr:
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(i, confidence=0.9):
pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(i, confidence=0.9))
break

print('Next Clicked')